# Polymer 1.0: how to make this custom element declarative?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, declarative, custom-element

Recently I've been trying to adapt to the declarative way of programming in Polymer. The custom element I'm trying to make work is called [Iron-Scroll-Spy](https://github.com/Zecat/iron-scroll-spy)

[Iron-Scroll-Spy Demo](http://zecat.github.io/iron-scroll-spy/components/iron-scroll-spy/)

**There demo code [(demo/index.html)](https://github.com/Zecat/iron-scroll-spy/blob/master/demo/index.html), looks like:**

[image]

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="scope">
    
  <paper-header-panel class="flex" id="headerPanel">
    <paper-toolbar>
      <paper-tabs selected="{{scrollSelected}}">
        <paper-tab>Section A</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>Section B</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>Section C</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>Section D</paper-tab>
      </paper-tabs>
    </paper-toolbar>
    
    <iron-scroll-spy selected="{{scrollSelected}}" id="scrollSpy">
      <div>
        <h1>Section A</h1>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, provident asperiores. Itaque quas architecto commodi, quam dicta beatae blanditiis obcaecati, voluptatibus, quisquam sint necessitatibus aliquid vero sunt dolor iusto quos!</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>Section B</h1>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, provident asperiores. Itaque quas architecto commodi, quam dicta beatae blanditiis obcaecati, voluptatibus, quisquam sint necessitatibus aliquid vero sunt dolor iusto quos!</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>Section C</h1>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, provident asperiores. Itaque quas architecto commodi, quam dicta beatae blanditiis obcaecati, voluptatibus, quisquam sint necessitatibus aliquid vero sunt dolor iusto quos!</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>Section D</h1>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, provident asperiores. Itaque quas architecto commodi, quam dicta beatae blanditiis obcaecati, voluptatibus, quisquam sint necessitatibus aliquid vero sunt dolor iusto quos!</span>
      </div>
    </iron-scroll-spy>
  </paper-header-panel>
  
  <script>
    var scope = document.getElementById("scope");
    scope.$.scrollSpy.scrollTarget = scope.$.headerPanel.scroller;
  </script>
  
</template>
```

---

### But how can I make there code work declartively?

If I wanted to make there demo page into my own `<custom-element>`, how could I do properly? Let's say for example I wanted to make it `<scroll-spy-app>`,,,

---

**What I've got so far (content not loading - not working):**

[image]

```
<dom-module id="scroll-spy-app">
<template>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; height: 100vh; }
        iron-scroll-spy div { padding: 250px 100px; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; }
    </style>

      <paper-header-panel class="flex" id="headerPanel">
        <paper-toolbar>
          <paper-tabs selected="{{scrollSelected}}">
            <paper-tab>Section A</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>Section B</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>Section C</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>Section D</paper-tab>
          </paper-tabs>
        </paper-toolbar>

        <iron-scroll-spy selected="{{scrollSelected}}" id="scrollSpy">
          <div class="scroll-spy">
            <h1>Section A</h1>
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, provident asperiores. Itaque quas architecto commodi, quam dicta beatae blanditiis obcaecati, voluptatibus, quisquam sint necessitatibus aliquid vero sunt dolor iusto quos!</span>
          </div>
          <div class="scroll-spy">
            <h1>Section B</h1>
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, provident asperiores. Itaque quas architecto commodi, quam dicta beatae blanditiis obcaecati, voluptatibus, quisquam sint necessitatibus aliquid vero sunt dolor iusto quos!</span>
          </div>
          <div class="scroll-spy">
            <h1>Section C</h1>
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, provident asperiores. Itaque quas architecto commodi, quam dicta beatae blanditiis obcaecati, voluptatibus, quisquam sint necessitatibus aliquid vero sunt dolor iusto quos!</span>
          </div>
          <div class="scroll-spy">
            <h1>Section D</h1>
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, provident asperiores. Itaque quas architecto commodi, quam dicta beatae blanditiis obcaecati, voluptatibus, quisquam sint necessitatibus aliquid vero sunt dolor iusto quos!</span>
          </div>
        </iron-scroll-spy>
      </paper-header-panel>

</template>

<script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'scroll-spy-app',

      properties: {
          scrollSelected: {
              type: Number,
              value: 0
          },
      },

      ready: function() {
        this.$.scrollSpy.scrollTarget = this.$.headerPanel.scroller;
      }
    });
</script>

</dom-module>
```

Comment: What means "not working"?

Comment: @JohannesReuter , specifically, the content isn't loading. Apologies for not being more clear on my issue. Updated question with images showing the problem.

Comment: I assume you are initializing the `scroll-spy-app`-element after the declaration using `<scroll-spy-app></scroll-spy-app>`?

Comment: correct. For this particular example, I'd import the custom element in the top of the page like... `<link rel="import" href="../scroll-spy-app.html">` and then I'd be able to include it like... `<scroll-spy-app></scroll-spy-app>`

Comment: Can you create a code snippet(jsbin, codepen, plunker) for the same. Nothing seems to be out of place in the code that you have posted. So far it looks more like import issue, which i am guessing its not

Comment: ugh! it was a freaking css issue!! min-height: 0; I'm kicking myself right now.

Comment: For good measure, here's the original demo inside jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oneeezy/uvgtgtmc/ ,,, and here's the declarative demo in a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oneeezy/r0dL02en/

Comment: One good thing came out of this... I finally learned how to use Polygit..haha.. thanks for all your help guys

Answer (score 0):

Ugh!... I actually had it right all along.

Next time, I just need to make sure my css `{ min-height: 0; }` isn't set to **ZERO**!

**Quick Answer:** [(Fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/oneeezy/r0dL02en/)

```
<script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'scroll-spy-app',

      ready: function() {
        this.$.scrollSpy.scrollTarget = this.$.headerPanel.scroller;
      }
    });
</script>
```

**Declarative Approach (full):**

```
<!--
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    Scroll Spy 
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: -->

<!-- Polymer -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-scroll-spy/iron-scroll-spy.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tab.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">



<dom-module id="scroll-spy-app">
<template>
    <style>
        :host {
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            -ms-flex-direction: column;
            -webkit-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
        }

        paper-header-panel { min-height: 100vh; }
        iron-scroll-spy div { min-height: 50vh; padding: 0 100px; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; }
    </style>

      <paper-header-panel id="headerPanel">

        <paper-toolbar>
          <paper-tabs selected="{{scrollSelected}}">
            <paper-tab>Section A</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>Section B</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>Section C</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>Section D</paper-tab>
          </paper-tabs>
        </paper-toolbar>


        <iron-scroll-spy selected="{{scrollSelected}}" id="scrollSpy">
          <div>
            <h1>Section A</h1>
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, provident asperiores. Itaque quas architecto commodi, quam dicta beatae blanditiis obcaecati, voluptatibus, quisquam sint necessitatibus aliquid vero sunt dolor iusto quos!</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h1>Section B</h1>
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, provident asperiores. Itaque quas architecto commodi, quam dicta beatae blanditiis obcaecati, voluptatibus, quisquam sint necessitatibus aliquid vero sunt dolor iusto quos!</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h1>Section C</h1>
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, provident asperiores. Itaque quas architecto commodi, quam dicta beatae blanditiis obcaecati, voluptatibus, quisquam sint necessitatibus aliquid vero sunt dolor iusto quos!</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h1>Section D</h1>
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, provident asperiores. Itaque quas architecto commodi, quam dicta beatae blanditiis obcaecati, voluptatibus, quisquam sint necessitatibus aliquid vero sunt dolor iusto quos!</span>
          </div>
        </iron-scroll-spy>

      </paper-header-panel>

</template>

<script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'scroll-spy-app',

      ready: function() {
        this.$.scrollSpy.scrollTarget = this.$.headerPanel.scroller;
      }
    });
</script>

</dom-module>
```

**Add Custom Element:**

```
<scroll-spy-app></scroll-spy-app>
```